# Refresh datatable after adding data?

Tags: json, ajax, datatable, datatables

I have data loaded in datatable. I want to add more data in table on click of link instead of redarwaing complete table

Here is mine data table code(I have added only relevant code here)

```
 function(){
       oTable=      $('#customerTable').dataTable({
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "iDisplayStart":0,
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,
                    "bRetrieve": true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "bAutoWidth": false,
                    "aaSorting": [[1,'desc']],
                    "aoColumns": [
                    {"aTargets": [0],"sName":"customer.fullName", "mData": function(response){
                        return response.customer.fullName;
                    }, "bSortable": false},
                    {"aTargets": [1],"sName":"updatedDate", "mData": function(response){
                        var updateDate = response.updatedDt;
                        return updateDate;
                    }, "bSortable": true},

                    ]

                    "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {


                            }
                        });
            }
```

When I do oTable.fnGetData(); // It displays rows

Here is mine add data code in data table

```
 for(i=0; i<jsonData.length;i++) {// i have debugged data is in right json format in js
            oTable.fnAddData(jsonData[i]);
            oTable.fnDraw();

    }
```

When I do `oTable.fnGetData()`  It displays rows 15 rows but still data is not displayed in my table . Also there is no error on browser console. Am i missing anything ?
Why data is not getting refreshed on table ?

Update :- Using datatable version 1.9.1

Comment: Attach sample data to the question. Also, the line `oTable.fnAddData(data[i]);` should be `oTable.fnAddData(jsondata[i]);`

Comment: Its complete web application where data comes from server side. I am not sure what you are looking for ? It was typo mistake in question.In actual code it is correct

Comment: Show us justs a sample row of that data you are getting from the server.

Comment: That made a lot more sense than the previous post :) See below,  `mData` was named `mDataProp` prior to 1.9.2, but nowadays it is hard to find a 1.9.1 sample using objects. It is more than 5 years old, and new releases where things changed came rapidly after that.

Answer (score 0):

hi you could use [Datatables Reload](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())

```
oTable.ajax.reload();
```

Comment: I am using old version of datatable i.e. 1.9.1.